# Construct url step by step - Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a url step by step but I can not do it.
I explain the situation: I realize an application for booking a coach online (step by step) with a angular material stepper.

Step 1: will be to go to myapp/booking/coachs url (for a list of coaches).

Step 2: grab the coach's id and add it to the url (myapp/booking/coachs/1).

Step 3: choose a date (myapp/booking/coachs/1/date/2018-07-13), then choose a time available -> (myapp/booking/coachs/1/date/2018-07-13/hour/9)

I can manage to get the id of the coach, etc., but I can not build the url step by step

Can someone guide me in the right direction to do that, please?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "build the url step by step" ? Maybe you could share a bit of code to let us understand what you've done so far.

Comment: Step by step, in the sense that when I select a coach, I go to step 2 and the url goes from myapp/booking/coach to myapp/booking/coach/2
Then when I select the date in step 2 the url goes to myapp/booking/coach/2/ date/2018-07-13.

I will gradually add information in the url

Comment: `router.navigate(['./childURL'])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hookup the `MatStepper` to a `FormGroup` and then set the url based on the form's current value you can get the intended functionality:

```
  // setup controls
  coachIdControl = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]);
  dateControl = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]);

  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    coachId: this.coachIdControl,
    date: this.dateControl
  });
```

To bind the form to the url and vice versa you can:

```
// take values from the url and use to populate the form and set current step
// (you can also use queryMap to use /coach/:id/date/:date url)
// if the user refreshes the page, the form will repopulate from the query
this._route.queryParamMap.subscribe(query => {

  if(query.has('coachId') && this.coachIdControl.value !== query.get('coachId')){
    this.coachIdControl.setValue(query.get('coachId'));
    this.matStepper.selectedIndex = 1;
  }

  let date = moment.isMoment(this.dateControl.value) ? this.dateControl.value.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null;

  if(query.has('date') && date !== query.get('date')){
    this.dateControl.setValue(query.get('date'));
    this.matStepper.selectedIndex = 2;
  }
  this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
});

// if the form changes, update the query params in the url
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this._router.navigate(['.'], {queryParams: {
    coachId: value.coachId,
    date: moment.isMoment(value.date) ? value.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null
  }});
});
```

The full example is here: [StackBlitz - angular-material-routed-stepper](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-routed-stepper)

### Update: Reset Steps

To remove url query values when stepping back you can listen for the `selectionChange` event and reset the values for steps that come after the selected step:

```
this.matStepper.selectionChange.subscribe((event: StepperSelectionEvent) => {


  switch(event.selectedIndex){
    case 0:
      this.dateControl.setValue(null);
    case 1:
      this.confirmControl.setValue(null);
  }

});
```

(Since the switch statements falls through, every step after the selected step will be reset.)

`setValue` will, in-turn, emit the `valueChanges` event which will update the url query.

The above [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-routed-stepper) is updated with this functionality.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, thank you so much , I could not hope better
@christiaan

Comment: This type of binding between the `Router` and `FormGroup` is useful for tables/indexes, stepped forms, etc. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hello @christiaan , I have another question. How I can reset the url on previous step ? If I'm on step 2 (booking?coachId=1&date=2018-07-02) and I'm going on step 1, I'd like to reset the date and have something like -> booking? CoachId = 1. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a shared service to the components that can hold onto the URL and add to it as you go through each step. Something like this:

```
export class URLService {

  private URL: string[] = [];

  public addToURL(segment: string): void {
    this.URL = [ ...this.URL, segment ];
  }

  public retrieveURL(): string {
    return this.URL.join('/');
  }

}
```

So inject the URLService into any component you are using to build the URL and each time you have a new item to add, call `urlService.addToURL('item')`. Then when you are ready for your full URL, call `urlService.retrieveURL()` to get a string that you can use.

Comment: Thank you @lordchangellor, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I create a first version, but you should change the normal input text for calendar input on case of date and selector for coachs ID's:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyxooylkovag

cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, this problem was secondary but it will help me to move forward :)